# What metric is it in the definition of converge in probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

What metric or norm is it in the definition of converge in probability ;

$ \forall \epsilon, \lim_{n} \mathbb{P}(\mid X_{n}-X \mid > \epsilon) \rightarrow 0 $ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

nobody seems to mention it, and I'm not a fan of deduction by examples. It seems reasonable to be uniformly.

Comment: You calculate $P(|X_n-X|>\varepsilon)$. This is a real number. So you obtain a sequence of real numbers. And you are saying that this sequence of real numbers converges to $0$, in the usual sense.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki but how does one calc. it ? The epsilon is dependent of what norm I use,right? Random variables are funtions right?

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki ah! Does it mean that $X_n$ and $X$ is realvalued? and the set at which they differ pointwise after evaluating more then epislon has probability zero.

Comment: Yes, random variables are functions, but you need to remind yourself what $(|X_n-X| > \varepsilon)$ means. It is the event, of all $\omega$ (in sample space), such that $|X_n(\omega) - X(\omega)| > \varepsilon$. Then you calculate the probability of this event, which is a real number, for every $n$. That gives you a sequence of real numbers.

Comment: "Pointwise" would mean something else. If we say $X_n\to X$ "pointwise", then we are saying that $X_n(\omega) \to X(\omega)$ for every $\omega$ (or a little better, almost every $\omega$). That is what "pointwise" would mean here. In probability theory, pointwise convergence of random variables is called "strong convergence". What you are asking is "weak convergence", it is a different notion.

Comment: This is a good question, if you state it right. You are asking whether there exists a metric *on some space of random variables* such that the convergence with respect to this metric coincides with convergence in probability.

Comment: @NicolasBourbaki I guess we are talking about the probabilty of the sets where the values of the R.V's differ more then epsilon then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are asking whether there exists a metric space structure on the space of random variables such that convergence in probability coincides with the convergence with respect to this metric. The answer is affirmative and you can read about it here: (look for "Ky Fan metric")

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Properties_2

Comment: Right, this is a good answer. But I think Nicolas Bourbakis comments are very insightfull aswell. This answer is more from a abstract mathemathical point on view, while Nicoulas is closer to the probability point of view. Both very insightfull. For pepole with limited math knowlegde the comments are probobaly more appropriate.